# How to get all products with pagination in WordPress Woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, pagination, product

Maybe this questions already asked but that not helpful for my question.

Am creating a `API` for my **WordPress** project. So i want to send `API` for to get all products with pagination.

I get products list using this code:

**android/all_products.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-load.php');
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I got all products, but i want to show products with pagination.

> Note: all the API's are written in inside android folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i creating a code and send the date using API.

```
 <?php
    require_once('../wp-load.php');
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

$brand_product_list = new WP_Query( $args);
    $pagination_count = 1;       
    while($brand_product_list->have_posts()) : $brand_product_list->the_post(); 

        $pagination_count++;

    endwhile; wp_reset_query();
//echo'<pre>';print_r($pagination_count/12); exit;
wp_reset_query();   
?>

<?php
    $pagination = round($pagination_count/12);
    for($i=1;$i<=$pagination;$i++)
    {
        $pagination_no[] = $i;
    ?>
    <!-- <a class="product-category-view-all" href="?pagination=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a> -->
    <?php } ?>

<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : $_GET['pagination'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

        $product_data = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if(!empty(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product_data->get_id())))
        {
            $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product_data->get_id());
        }
        else
        {
            $img = "";
        }

        $product_list[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product_data->get_id(),
            'product_name' => $product_data->get_title(),
            'product_regular_price' => $product_data->get_regular_price(),
            'product_sale_price' => $product_data->get_sale_price(),
            'product_price' => $product_data->get_price(),
            'img' => $img,
            'rating' => $product_data->get_average_rating(),
            'stock_quantity' => $product_data->get_stock_quantity(),
            'stock' => $product_data->is_in_stock(),
        );
    endwhile; wp_reset_query();
    $data[] = array(
        'pagination' => $pagination_no,
        'product_list' => $product_list
    );

    //echo json_encode($peoduct_list, $pagination)
    echo json_encode($data)
?>
```

Comment: Using "custom WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce" and is not the best practice", as stated [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

Answer (score 1):

*below pagination code is to show next products you can also do it to show previous product by applying same method*

```
if(isset( $_GET['page_num'] ) ) {
        $page_number = $_GET['page_num'];
} else {
    $page_number = 2;
}
    $args = array (
        'limit' => 3,
        'page' => $page_number,
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    foreach( $products as $product ) {`enter code here`
      //your data here
      // e.g $product_name = $product->get_name();
    }
    <a href="?page_num=<?php echo ++$page_number; ?>">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create API's then just use `Woocommerce` rest API's which are built in function given in wordpress please use below url it will give you list of products with lots of options:

```
{{your_url}}/wp-json/wc/v2/products
```

Go to wp-admin and go to Woocommerce -> settings -> API

-> Enable rest API
-> Go to Key/Apps and create Auth Keys both secret and Private (Copy that keys)

Then give this above url to add it for use in application with o_auth of secret key and private key.

Please see this link for all `woocommerce API's` : https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product

Comment: I have already create this flow. I just want code for pagination

Comment: Okay then use auth and give above url for api

Comment: `per_page` is argument for this

Comment: `API` run in my local server.

Comment: Sorry bro i can't understand what you say :(